# background image size (move slowly)

Tags: c#

I have some problem.
I set a back ground image to my form. and i decreased the size of the picture to about 300 Kb. But yet when i start the program and when i wanna change the location of form, the form move slowly and with lag.
On the other hand if i decrease the size of picture more, it will be smaller than the form.
Some works that i tried is : decrease the size of image and change the images to tile and stretch. But i couldn't see what i'm waiting for.. 
What can i do now ?
Is there any code or advice for solve this problem ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking but the first thing you need is understand that the file size is irrelevant to your problem; lagging animation comes only from the number of pixels you are moving. But then you seems to say that you are not moving the image but the form itself? It should move the same ways with or without a background image, no? You hould show us the moving code and also tell us the dimensions of form and image! You are using winforms, right? Always a problematic choice for animations!

Comment: when i move form, form will move with lag and when i delete picture from form it will move fast without any lag.

Comment: Do you mean move by hand??

Comment: Yes !
Move by mouse coursor

Comment: I think you mean the lag happens when you hold mouse on title bar then move by drag the window?

Comment: Yeah i exactly mean this.
Now this is my question :
Is there any code or suggestion to solve this problem ?